# Custom allocator method is not called

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

I am trying to learn and write a self custom allocator - I was expecting that the cout statement should be printed but it never does - what is the wrong am I doing - how to write custom allocator:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template < class T >
class MyAllocator : public std::allocator<T> {
public:
    T* allocate(size_t size)
    {
        std::cout << "Allocation request size " << size << std::endl;
        return new T[size];
    }

};

int main()
{
    std::vector <int, MyAllocator<int>> x;
    x.push_back(10);
    x.push_back(10);
    x.push_back(10);

    for (auto& var : x)
        std::cout << "Value " << var << std::endl;

}
```

Output

```
Value 10
Value 10
Value 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inheritance of the standard allocator is not needed. Remove the inheritance `: public std::allocator<T>` and the compiler will be kind to inform you about what you missed to implement. Until C++17 the method `construct` must be implemented and it is used in `std::vector`, not `allocate`. Also `value_type`, `deallocator` and `destroy` are missing.

```
template< class U, class... Args >
void construct( U* p, Args&&... args );
```

Since you haven't implemented it and your allocator inherits the standard allocator, `std::allocator::construct` is called, that does not produce output.

### Why you should not inherit std::allocator

The answer on this question is simple on the one hand and not simple in practice on the other hand.

1. Like other classes in C++ standard library, `std::allocator` does not have a virtual destructor, so it should not be inherited, if it is not explicitly indicated like in `std::enable_shared_from_this`.
2. Standard containers don't use `class Allocator` directly. They use [`std::allocator_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits). It helps to implement minimal user-defined allocators. If you implement only `value_type`, `allocate` and `deallocate` members of `MyAllocator`, `std::allocator_traits<MyAllocator>` makes `MyAllocator` fully conformed to [C++ named requirements: *Allocator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator).

   - Let look at your `MyAllocator` carefully. It inherits `std::allocator` and "replaces" [`std::allocator::allocate (2)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/allocate).
   - Let read [`std::allocator_traits::allocate (2)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits/allocate) reference manual, that is called by `std::vector`:

     > Calls `a.allocate(n, hint)` if possible. **If not possible** (e.g. a has no two-argument member function allocate()), calls `a.allocate(n)`.

   What you have reached. You have implemented `MyAllocator::allocate(std::size_t n)` (2), but not `MyAllocator::allocate(std::size_t n, const void* hint)` (1), it is inherited from `std::allocator`. It is called from `std::vector`, that is not what you expected. If you had not inherited `std::allocator`, your implementation `MyAllocator::allocate` would be called.

Comment: I made changes as mentioned and added the construct method in my class just printing a statement there to see if code flow comes there but still the same output - I do not see the code executing any of mine's allocator method getting called

Comment: It's impossible. Please edit your question and show your updates.

Comment: Thanks for the example - can you please let me know why inheritance : public std::allocator<T> is not required or the code fails?

Comment: I've extended the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're half way there. As described [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator), the standard describes custom allocator classes having several optional and required named attributes and methods. If you want your example to work, at least you must implement the required ones. These are:

- add a `value_type`.
- add an `allocate(n)` method. Takes a size_t input and returns an address.
- add a `deallocate(p, n)` method. Takes two inputs and has no output.

You must also remove the inheritance to `std::allocator` (see @S.M.'s answer). Example similar to your MyAllocator class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

template < class T >
class MyAllocator
{
public:
    T * allocate(size_t size)
    {
        std::cout << "Allocation request size => " << size << std::endl;
        return new T[size];
    }
    void deallocate(T * p_t, size_t n)
    {
        std::free(p_t);
    }
    using value_type = T;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector <int, MyAllocator<int>> x;
    x.push_back(10);
    x.push_back(10);
    x.push_back(10);

    for (auto& var : x)
        std::cout << "Value " << var << std::endl;

}
```